# Enum's ability to implement part of the business logic

Tags: java, enums, refactoring

Trying to refactor the code. Now the code is:

```
if ("objects".equals(type)) {
    Object oldJson = oldData.get("content");
    Object newJson = newData.get("content");
} else if ("objects.appeals".equals(type)) {
    Object oldJson = oldData.get("data").get("person");
    Object newJson = newData.get("data").get("person");
}
```

The number of types is much larger. I gave only 2 for an example. Trying to optimize with enum:

```
    public enum HistoryUpdateTypeEnum {
        OBJECTS("objects", new Document()),
        APPEALS_OBJECTS("appeals.objects", new Document());

        HistoryUpdateTypeEnum(String type, Document documentSlice) {
            this.type = type;
            this.documentSlice = documentSlice;
        }

        private String type;
        private Document documentSlice;

        public static HistoryUpdateTypeEnum fromString(String value) {
            return Stream.of(values())
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .filter(v -> v.name().replaceAll("_",".").equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                    .findAny()
                    .orElse(null);
        }

        public Object formSlice(Document data) {
            this.documentSlice = data;
            return documentSlice.get("content"); // How to make it universal?
        }
    }
```

And use:

```
HistoryUpdateTypeEnum typeEnum = HistoryUpdateTypeEnum.fromString("objects.appeals");
Document oldData = new Document(......).append(..., ...);
Document newData = new Document(......).append(..., ...);
Object oldJson = typeEnum.formSlice(oldData);
Object newJson = typeEnum.formSlice(newData);
```

I can’t figure out how to make me perform my action for each type. That is, documentSlice.get ("content") for 'objects' or documentSlice.get("data").get("person") for 'appeals.objects'. Are there any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible variants is abstract method in your `Enum` class:

```
public enum HistoryUpdateTypeEnum {

    OBJECTS {
        @Override
        Object getJson(Document data) {
            return data.get("objects");
        }
    },

    ...

    abstract Object getJson(Document data);
}
```

Then you could use it in such way:

```
HistoryUpdateTypeEnum history = HistoryUpdateTypeEnum .valueOf(type.toUpperCase());
Object oldJson = history.getJson(oldData);
Object newJson = history.getJson(newData);
```